# A norm invariant under permutations but not under signed permutations

Tags: permutations, normed-spaces, symmetry, symmetric-functions

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We call it **axes-symmetric** if $\|x\|$ does not depend on the order of the components of $x$. Equivalently if $\|x\| = \|P \cdot x \|$ for any permutation matrix.

**Question:** If a norm is axes-symmetric, is it invariant under **[signed permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix#Signed_permutation_group)**? (i.e $\|(x_1,...,x_n)\| = \|(\pm x_1,...,\pm x_n) \|$ ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$\|(x_1,x_2)\|^2 = x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2.$$ This relation defines a norm on $\Bbb R^2$.

Clearly, $$\|(x_1,x_2)\|=\|(x_2,x_1)\|\ne \|(x_1,-x_2)\|.$$

**edit**

Write this norm in terms of a matrix $A=\frac 12 \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ and scalar product:

$$\|\vec x\|^2 = \vec x^TA\vec x = (A\vec x,\vec x).$$
The matrix $A$ is positive definite (symmetric with eigenvalues $\frac 12$ and $\frac 32$), hence the map $(\vec x,\vec y)\to (A\vec x,\vec y)$ defines an inner product. This ensures us that the map $\vec x\to \sqrt{(A\vec x,\vec x)}$ is a norm. This norm is called sometimes the *energy norm given by the positive definite matrix $A$*.

In general case $A=A^T>0$, proving the triangle inequality for the corresponding energy norm is equivalent to proving that $\vec x^TA\vec y\le \sqrt {\vec x^TA\vec x}\sqrt {\vec y^TA\vec y}$, which can be obtained by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to scalar product of vectors $\sqrt A \vec x$ and $\sqrt A\vec y$. The matrix $\sqrt A$ is defined as a unique symmetric positive definite matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you know any easy (quick) proof that the norm you suggested satisfies the triangle inequality? (I succeeded proving this to myself, but only via a long technical calculation...)

Comment: @AsafShachar I added the proof that this is a norm - I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I think that after you say $(\vec x,\vec y)\to (A\vec x,\vec y)$ is an inner product you can stop there. (An inner product always induces a norm, the triangle inequality follows from cauchy-schwartz)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought it would be nice to see a picture:

The ellipse in the picture below is the unit sphere of the norm suggested by
TZakrevskiy:

$\{(x,y)|x^2 + xy +y^2 =1\}$

[image: function]

From looking at the picture, it's clear that this norm is not invariant under sign changes of a coordinate.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. What about now?

Comment: Now everything looks fine.